# Phalcon: Storing related records (Implicit Transactions) issue

Tags: phalcon

I have 3 tables/models. They have 1-1 relationship. Each user have only one profile and only one contact address.

When a visitor registers an new account in my website, I will create new records in each user, profile, address table. To ensure data integrity, I think I have to use transaction here. So I used "Storing related records (Implicit Transactions)" in Phalcon documentation to do this but I met an issue.

A new record inserted into address but the address fk in profile always is null?? Everything is ok but `aid` fk is always null.

```
User:
-uid
-email
-password
-(other records)

Profile:
-uid
-aid (address id)
-name
-age
-phone
-(other records)

Address:
-aid
-province
-district
-(other records)

class User extends Model {
    public function initialize() {
        $this->hasOne('uid', 'Profile', 'uid');
    }
}

class Profile extends Model {
    public function initialize() {
        $this->hasOne('uid', 'User', 'uid');
        $this->hasOne('aid', 'Address', 'aid');
    }
}

class Address extends Model {
    public function initialize() {
        $this->hasOne('aid', 'Profile', 'aid');
    }
}
```

How to solve this issue? Or I have to use Isolated Transactions manually?
Thank for you help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add the address after you create the user but before you create the profile? Then the Profile table should have access to the uid and aid.

It appears to me as if it's just working in the order they are created and doesn't then go back to do an update. Alternatively you could also add a uid column to the Address table, that way you would be able to map by that. This might also be handy if you just needed a user and an address rather than a profile at some point.